# One computer, 3 Monitors 1 TV switch 1 Monitor for TV

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, external-display, kvm-switch

I have a 3 screen setup with a TV next to the monitors. I was wanting to occasionally switch the 3rd monitor out for the TV (before i was having to go under the desk and switch the HDMI cables around)

I bought this:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0049S6ZUS?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00

Which i believed would allow me to easily switch between monitor and TV. But it doesn't seem to be working.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like it switches by active Signals but you can use the remote to automatically switch. So looks like you would just need to setup with device with the connection to your 3rd monitor and your tv.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the device description, it appears that you can use it to switch between multiple video sources, using a single display device. So for example, if you have an XBox and a DVD player, you can switch between the two using your television.

The device does not appear to support what you are asking for, which is to use a single source (e.g. XBOX) and output that to multiple displays (TV & Monitor).

If you look at the one of the images from the product page, you can see that the supported configuration is for multiple sources and a single display:

---

[image: hdmi-switch]

---

Comment: I think i was thinking more it was made for that but it could be used to do other things as it was just an input and output. My bad. Do you know what i could get that would do what i need?

Comment: I have not used the devices personally, but try googling either "hdmi splitter" or "dual monitor kvm".